# A closed form for $\int_{1/{\sqrt{3}}}^{1/{\sqrt{2}}} \frac{1}{a^2 m^2+1} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{m^2}\sqrt{-2 m^2+1}\right) \, dm$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Is there a closed form for

$$\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \frac{\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{-2 m^2+1}}{m^2}\right)}{a^2 m^2+1} \, dm
$$
where $a$ is parameter.

Integrating by parts:
$$\int_{1/3\,\sqrt {3}}^{1/2\,\sqrt {2}}\!{\frac {m\arctan \left( am
 \right) }{\sqrt {-2\,{m}^{2}+1} \left( -{m}^{2}+1 \right) }}\,{\rm d}
m
$$

and by replacing  $m=sin(t)$

$$\int_{\arcsin \left( 1/3\,\sqrt {3} \right) }^{\pi/4}\!{\frac {\arctan
 \left( a\sin \left( t \right)  \right) \sin \left( t \right) }{\cos
 \left( t \right) \sqrt {2\, \left( \cos \left( t \right)  \right) ^{2
}-1}}}\,{\rm d}t
$$

and......

I tried everything, but I still can not solve it. Any Ideas?

Comment: What is the source of such problem? Can you give us a taste of the *everything* you have tried? Have you tried integration by parts and/or differentiation under the integral sign?

Comment: Yes I tired integration by parts and/or differentiation under the integral sign,but can not solve :(

Comment: By integration by parts it is enough to compute $$ \int_{1/\sqrt{3}}^{1/\sqrt{2}}\frac{m\arctan(am)}{(1-m^2)\sqrt{1-2m^2}}\,dm $$ and by replacing $m$ with $\sin\theta$ we get something resembling Coxeter/Ahmed's integrals.